# Outlook to Excel

Tags: email, outlook, automation

I get email alerts almost constantly, which I am required to process and put into an excel spreadsheet.  Is there a way that I can automate this ?

I have all of the messages going into a specific folder in Outlook 2010. I want to be able to pick out key information from these messages and stick them in excel for further analysis.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider developing a VBA macro or an add-in if you need to distribute the solution on multiple PCs. If you just need to automate Outlook, see [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0).

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

Also you may handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class which is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Be aware, the event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than 16).

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.